# A function with a timeout and a value++ not changing active class as needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

```
function anim() {
            clearTimeout(animTimeout);              
            $('#wrap .bullet').removeClass('active');
            imageindex++;
            $('#wrap .bullet:nth-child('+ imageindex +')').addClass('active');
            $('#wrap .images img').fadeOut();
            $('#wrap .images img:nth-child('+ imageindex +')').fadeIn();
            if($('#wrap .images img').length == imageindex) {
                imageindex = 0;
            }

    animTimeout = setTimeout(anim, 1500);
}
```

This is the function. It does change pictures, fades them in and out really well. It is a slideshow, the .bullet is just a circle where by clicking on you can jump to a certain picture.

This function works by the way, it lets you jump to what ever picture you selected:

```
        $('#wrap .bullets a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
            $('#wrap .images img').stop().attr('style', '');
            imageindex = parseInt($(this).data('i') );
            anim();
        });
```

However, I want the current pictures bullet to be active so you don't lets say jump on the picture that was the previous one etc...

The effect the anim() function gives me is that on the very first slide, all the ".bullet"-s get a class of active and from the second slide they don't have it anymore til it gets back to the first slide again. Why is this? If the imageindex is growing, I see no reason for behavior like this... Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Two things that may be the root of your problem

1- anim may be triggered several times
2- imageindex is unstable

I'd suggest you add `console.log('anim with ' + imageindex)` statement to beginning of anim to check number of times anim gets called and the value of imageindex

Also ensure you are declaring your imageindex variable above any other js function that uses it.

Comment: I actually found a solution for this - using the nth-child selector didn't work, but $($('#wrap .bullet').get(imageindex)).addClass('active'); did

Answer (score 0):

In your case, i would replace your global variable imageIndex which is not required to do what you're trying to achieve.

replace it by this code :

```
var animTimeout = null;

function anim() {
    clearTimeout(animTimeout);
    var activeIndex = $('#wrap .bullet.active') // select the active bullet
                         .removeClass('active') // remove its 'active' class
                         .next().addClass('active') // put 'active' class to the next item
                         .index(); // retrieve the new active item index
    if (activeIndex < 0) {
        // if end of list reached, put it on the first item
        activeIndex = $('#wrap .bullet').first().addClass('active').index();
    }
    // cancel previous animations before starting fadeOut and fadeIn
    $('#wrap .images img').stop().fadeOut().eq(activeIndex).fadeIn();
    animTimeout = setTimeout(anim, 1500);
}

$('#wrap .bullets a').click(function(e) {
    $('#wrap .images img').stop().attr('style', '');
    $('#wrap .bullet').removeClass('active');
    $('#wrap .bullet').eq($(this).parent().index() - 1).addClass('active');
    anim();
});
```